# "WordPress in X-Cart" issue

Tags: wordpress, x-cart

I have installed and configured 'WordPress in X-Cart' module for an X-Cart 4.6.4 Gold site.
When I enable the module from the X-Cart admin, the x-cart front-end crashes, with an "Error establishing a database connection. Cannot use object of type W3_Config as array in /home/[username]/public_html/include/func/func.db.php on line 517" message, in a blank page.
The X-Cart back-end works ok and when I disable the module, x-cart front-end works again.
Also, both WordPress front-end and admin work ok when I enter directly in the WordPress site. The WP site is located in the X-Cart root.

I found a solution which I am not sure if it is the perfect, but temporarily it works.
I tried to trace the code with a debugger in my local dev. server and I found out that in **/wp-includes/ms-settings.php** WP script file, close to line 57, the code searches for the current blog, by querying the WP database, via the input path in the browser. This is stored in the **$current_blog** variable, via the snippet:

```
if ( 0 === strcasecmp( $current_site->domain, $domain ) && 0 === strcasecmp( $current_site->path, $path ) ) {
            $current_blog = get_site_by_path( $domain, $path );
        } elseif ( '/' !== $current_site->path && 0 === strcasecmp( $current_site->domain, $domain ) && 0 === stripos( $path, $current_site->path ) ) {
            // If the current network has a path and also matches the domain and path of the request,
            // we need to look for a site using the first path segment following the network's path.
            $current_blog = get_site_by_path( $domain, $path, 1 + count( explode( '/', trim( $current_site->path, '/' ) ) ) );
        } else {
            // Otherwise, use the first path segment (as usual).
            $current_blog = get_site_by_path( $domain, $path, 1 ); // REPLACED LINE
        }
```

The $current_blog variable was set to false, thus, leading to further empty object regarding the found current WP site and exiting the procedure, displaying the "Error establishing a database connection" message.

From what I noticed, the **$path** variable was set to the x-cart root dir relative path (eg, if xcart is installed in /xcart root dir and the WP blog in /xcart/blog/ dir, then the **$path** variable was set to '/xcart/', leaving out the blog path part, thus not finding the blog.
On the other hand, the **$current_site->path value** contains the path to the blog (/xcart/blog/), so I replaced the above line (comment: 'REPLACED LINE') with the one below:

```
 $current_blog = get_site_by_path($domain, $current_site->path);
```

Also, I did the following things:
- I removed any mod_rewrite rules in the .htaccess file of the WordPress root directory, because they broke the initial redirection
- I tried to remove my code tweak posted in this thread, but then the site displayed the database connection error, so I retrieved it back.
- I deactivated the **W3 Total Cache** plugin in WordPress, because it kept breaking the site.

The strange thing is that I needed to keep my code tweak as well.
Anyway, the integration worked fine.

My question is if my above approach regarding the code modification is correct, since I actually modified the original WordPress code which is hardly possible to have a bug in this spot.

Comment: What does line 517 say?

Comment: @Aibrean:
line 517 is in bold snippet: 
    if ( 
            stristr($query, "select ") !== false  
            **&& isset($config['General']['use_old_products_lng'])**  
            && $config['General']['use_old_products_lng'] == 'Y'  
        ) {  
            $query = func_transform_lng_query_ext($query, 'xcart_products_lng');  
            $query = func_transform_lng_query_base($query, 'xcart_products', $sql_tbl    ['products_lng_current']);  
        }

Comment: Please put this in your original question and format within code. See the help for how to format code.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed replay, but I found a questionable solution related to code modification to another part of the code. I have edited my initial question, adding this solution.